# Bootstrap datepicker - Set maxDate in UTC time instead of local time

Tags: eonasdan-datetimepicker

I'm using **[eonasdan bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker)**. I'm trying to work in UTC time (including hours) but **maxDate seems to refer to local time**.

An **example** would be if I want to **limit the time to 10:00 am UTC time. I want the datetimepicker to allow time modification but no longer than 10:00 am UTC time. Because I'm +3 timezone, I'm able to go until 13:00 pm.**

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vvtwq0xm/1/

```
var dateUTCtime = new Date().toISOString();
alert('UTC time = ' + dateUTCtime);

var opts = {
    format: "DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm",
    stepping: 5,
    maxDate: dateUTCtime,
    useCurrent: true,
    sideBySide: false,
    showTodayButton: true,
    widgetPositioning: {
        'vertical': 'bottom'
    }
};

$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
```

**My date is in UTC but maxTime seems to not respect time (hour) to UTC. It allows me to go until current local time**.

Anyway to make it work on UTC?

ps: I added some explanation for better understanding. I'm interested in respecting UTC date and time (hours).

Answer (score 0):

In version `4.17.37` timezone integration was added (see [changelog](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Changelog/#41737)), while you are using version `4.14.30` of the datetimepicker in your fiddle.

To use the picker with UTC, add [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) to your imports and set `maxDate` using [`moment.utc()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/).

Here a working example (using lastest picker version: `4.17.42`):

```js
var opts = {
  format: "DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm",
  stepping: 5,
  maxDate: moment.utc(),
  useCurrent: true,
  sideBySide: false,
  showTodayButton: true,
  widgetPositioning: {
    'vertical': 'bottom'
  }
};

$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker(opts);
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.42/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.5/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.42/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
  <input type='text' class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution is having the issue that I meant. I'm in different timezone than UTC. Still when I go to the clock I can modify this one until my current local time despite the maxDate was modified to UTC. What I'm looking for is a way to lock the hours edition to UTC time instead of my local time.

Comment: I modified slightly the description of my problem. Probably I didn't express myself well. Hopefully now it's better.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I solved the UTC issue, but I was wrong, I did few test, anyway I'll investigate further to find a better solution.